# MySQL Table Insert Incorrectly Fails on Foreign Key Error After 580 Rows Inserted

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

On a simple table insert MYSQL constnatly fails on the 581st row and throws the following error:

```
INSERT interface (interface,status,description,deviceID) VALUES("Et34-10G","down","nodesc","1977")
INSERT interface (interface,status,description,deviceID) VALUES("Et35-10G","down","nodesc","1977")
INSERT interface (interface,status,description,deviceID) VALUES("Et36-10G","down","nodesc","1977")
INSERT interface (interface,status,description,deviceID) VALUES("Et37-10G","up","chic-02","1977")
INSERT interface (interface,status,description,deviceID) VALUES("Et38-10G","up","chic-06","1977")
INSERT interface (interface,status,description,deviceID) VALUES("Et39-10G","up","chic-07","1977")
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails    (`dcss`.`interface`, CONSTRAINT `deviceID` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `device` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) at ./import_intstate_into_dcssdb.pl line 27.
```

It always fails on inserting the 581th row.

```
| 576 | Et34-10G     | down   | nodesc  |     1977 |
| 577 | Et35-10G     | down   | nodesc  |     1977 |
| 578 | Et36-10G     | down   | nodesc  |     1977 |
| 579 | Et37-10G     | up     | chic-02 |     1977 |
| 580 | Et38-10G     | up     | chic-06 |     1977 |
+-----+--------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
580 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I cannot understand why it was able to insert the previous rows with the same deviceID (1977) but throws at error consistently on the 581st row.

I have tested this and gotten the same results piping in the raw SQL statements.

```
-bash-4.1$ mysql -u root -p dcss < test.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 581: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails     (`dcss`.`interface`, CONSTRAINT `deviceID` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `device` (`id`) ON  DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I am at a loss to explain this.  The parent table has this id in it so there is not reason it should be failing on a constraint issue.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM device WHERE id=1977;
   +------+-------------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------------+---------------+------+-------+
| id   | fqdn                    | ipv4addr      | ipv6addr         | datacenterID | typeID |     make   | model        | serial_number | os   | shell |
+------+-------------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------------+---------------+------+-------+
| 1977 | ls03.router | 10.10.255.210 | unk |            1 |      2 | ARISTA | DCS-7050S-64 |    1234567   | EOS  | unk   |
```

+------+-------------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------------+---------------+------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

Mate, can you look closer at the data that you try to insert as row 581?
I guess there is some special symbol there that is preventing the correct way to cast the string `"1977"` to integer `1977`.

Try to insert it like that:
`INSERT interface (interface,status,description,deviceID) VALUES("Et39-10G","up","chic-07", 1977);`

Tell me how this is working for you.

Comment: I tried exactly that and the insert from the CLI works fine. I've tried mixing up the source data and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with what the data is. Only that it fails on the 581st insert.

Comment: How you generate those inserts? Probably there is a special symbol that mess with the cast to integer. If it works from CLI ... no other explanation really.

Comment: That is what I am thinking. Let me test some more.